# Dreamforce SFSE swag

Tags: discussion

To our community members who will be attending Dreamforce SFSE, I'd like to send you some salesforce.se swag to give out at the conference. I'm having the tshirts and stickers made right now. The turn around time is roughly 2 weeks. Since we're a bit tight on time, I feel it'd be better if I have our vendor send you the swag package at the hotel you're staying in SF instead of your home address(unless you actually live in SF area). This way you'll have less stuff to put in your luggage case!

So for those who are going, could you please email me at jin@stackexchange.com with your name, hotel name/mailing address, and your date of arrival at the hotel.

P.S. we're still planning to send out the official top user swag later. This swag package is separate from that.

**UPDATE Oct 1st**

Thank you for emailing me your info. It turned out a lot of you(20+) are going to Dreamforce! I sent your mailing info to our vendor. You will receive the swag package on Oct 10th(or Oct 13th at the latest). I appreciate your help trying to promote this awesome community, have a great time at Dreamforce!

Comment: You'll probably want t-shirt size too?

Comment: @metadaddy we'll send several tshirts that cover different sizes.

Comment: @metadaddy on second thought, send your own shirt size too.

Comment: Done! you should have an email from me :-)

Comment: Sent an email. I'd be happy to pass out at the women in tech events. Will there be women's sizes/styles for shirts?

Comment: @mpusto we should be able to.

Comment: DONE -- email on the way

Comment: I've sent an e-mail over! Cheers @Jin

Comment: Sent Email, Thanks !!!

Comment: Awesome, thanks for doing this @Jin.

Comment: Who can get access to the swag? Anyone? Me? Really??

Comment: I'm definetely getting in on the swag pack, email sent!

Comment: @metadaddy What's the deal with giving stuff out during sessions? Do we just throw swag at the audience and hope for the best? :)

Comment: @DanielBallinger However you like - best question, random, most elegant Salesforce Developer Evangelist - it's up to you!

Comment: @metadaddy All good ideas! It sounds like there will be a good amount of SFSE swag to go around.

Comment: Email sent - @Jin, look forward to sporting my SFSE T-shirts during my Dreamforce sessions!

Comment: 17 of you sent me emails so far. That's a nice sized group! Hopefully you won't have trouble finding each other if you all wear the tshirts :)

Comment: @DanielBallinger Our DUG often will use raffle tickets when giving away swag (everyone who attends gets one) and does a drawing at the end of the meeting. I don't know how large the attendance at your session will be, but that's one way of doing it.

Comment: Emailed the details just now.

Comment: Email sent successfully! @Jin looking forward for swag pack.

Comment: @Jin, We have a decent chunk of SFSE members at the NYC DUG. I'd love to have some swag to hand out at our meeting right after dreamforce.

Comment: @Jin - Just sent an email w/ my info.  Hopefully I'm not too late. thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

@Jin thats awesome :-)

as I asked before in your other post, what about people missing Dreamforce ? (just being jealous & missed out)

will you be able to send some across to different Developer Group Leaders to distribute in one of our monthly DUG meetups ? (need not be an immediate one, maybe at a later time)

Comment: We'll be mailing out a swag package to top users(on the first 2 pages, by rep of all time) later. Our community team will probably also send out swag package to meetup events too.

Comment: @Jin is that still happening ?

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke yes! our community manager who's in charge of this has been on leave for family matters. Another community manager will contact you guys soon. Sorry about the delay!

Comment: @Jin I still think this hasn't happend .. yet it'd be an awesome encouragement to our top users.

Comment: It is happening! I promise! Love, "another community manager" still climbing out of the backlog

Answer (score 0):

I received my swag and Jin thoughtfully included shirts of every size.  As such, I have some extras if someone would like them

3 large
1 XL
1 XXL

you can send me a [message](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2602/crop1645)  and we can take offline how to get the shirt to you

Comment: I definitely want one! :)

Comment: PepeFloyd -- email me by looking at the address here: http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2602/crop1645

Comment: Thanks, emails  in SE are private, I can't see it in your profile. Here is my email address pepefloyd@gmail.com Thanks!

Answer (score -7):

Swag? Are we 15 year old girls?

Comment: I fear you're confusing 'swagger' in its modern usage, often shortened to 'swag', with 'swag' which has a venerable usage meaning 'that which is stolen by a thief', or 'loot', 'booty'. And by extension, here 'free stuff'.